# query to count the number of entries with appears only once in rails activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to find out the number of elements which appears only once in a table.

**in sql**

select count(*) from (SELECT count(*),id FROM trans GROUP BY id  HAVING count(*)=1) temptable

How can this be done in rails active record?

there are millions of records in the table.

Comment: Did u  heared DISTINCT??? in sql

Answer (score 2):

what exectly you want ... ??? sorry but i didn't understand your requirement....

what you have done is good and right one (only one modification is there count(*****))...

although you can remove select * from your query...

simply you can write

```
SELECT count(*),id FROM trans GROUP BY id HAVING count(*)=1
```

it will also give the same result with more performance

-- edit / update

as you want to know about the count of this result then you can apply count(*) on this query

as -

```
  SELECT count(*) from ( select id FROM trans GROUP BY id HAVING count(*)=1)
```

Comment: i just need the count of the above result

Comment: when i saw your question then it was not counting the result of this subquery.... there was 'select * from' .. so i thnought you have done one mistake and that's why you are getting a problem and i can intimate you to look on this error

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
`Trans.find(:all, :select => 'COUNT(*)', :group => 'trans.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1')`

Comment: this gives me the total hash. i just want the count of the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
find_by_sql("SELECT count(*) from ( select id FROM trans GROUP BY id HAVING count(*)=1)")
```